# intel vtune show only splash but doesn't run

Tags: windows, intel-vtune

Install oneapi_vtune_p_2021.7.1.471_offline(windows) without errors. After run I see splash screen about 20 second and then nothing. I tried to reinstall, but nothing. Tried to remove folder "AppData\Roaming\Intel" nothing.

Running with `vtune-gui --log-to-console --log-level=debug` shows me "[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\vtune\latest\bin64-1']".

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running VTune using a user account with Unicode characters in its name. This would be addressed in  future VTune releases. Sorry for the inconvenience. As a temporary workaround please run VTune with a user account that has ASCII chars only. You could do Run As... to avoid switching between accounts.